# How to import angular innerHTML in standalone component

Tags: angular, angular-standalone-components

With the new standalone component, in Angular 15, we can now import dependencies directly in the `@component`declaration.

We can also import only `NgIf` instead of the `CommonModule` to make our component more three-shakable.

But I was wondering how to import the `innerHTML` one.

Did somebody find it ?

*I saw that the `eDomAdapter` had the `createHtmlDocument` method, but I cannot import that*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`innerHtml`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is not a directive, it a native attribute of `Element`. There is nothing to import.

Comment: Make this even easier, thx a lot <3

Answer (score 0):

You can use innerHtml like this without importing anything,
HTML File:

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlStr"></div>
```

Typescript File:

```
htmlStr: string = 'Plain Text Example &amp; <strong>Bold Text Example</strong>';
```